# Was Gally always himself?

Tags: the-maze-runner, james-dashner

**Book ending spoiler alerts!!**

In the Maze Runner book, Gally runs into the maze after a Gathering is held between all of the Keepers.

> Gally later goes missing until the end of the book when the Gladers get out of the maze. Ava, the scientist reveals there is one more Variable. Gally mentions "They... can... control me". Then he throws a knife killing Chuck under the control of the Creators.

When Gally snapped in the Gathering, was he pissed off, or was he under control of the creators the whole time?

Comment: I added the spoiler tags, but I don't really know exactly how much should be behind it. The title may need editing too.

Comment: I suspect the title should be edited a bit. Probably less of an issue for someone who only saw the movie (like me), but I imagine a person who has just begun the book would find this to be quite a big spoiler.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw what if I make the title something like "Was Gally always himself?"

Comment: "Was Gally always himself?" sounds good - makes little sense to someone without at least some knowledge of the book.

Answer (score 1):

> Gally was himself in the gathering. The only bit he was being controlled in was the bit where he killed Chuck. He was always annoyed because he didn't like the fact that Thomas had gone into the maze and broken rules and he felt that the punishment Thomas had was not severe enough for the crime he had committed,

Hope that helps I have more information abut Gally but if you want me to edit the question then let me know